# Unable to render Scattertext HTML output

Tags: python, plot, anaconda

I am using a Juypter Notebook and continue to get Error 404: Not Found when attempting to generate HTML output for the scattertext package.

```
import scattertext as st
from IPython.display import IFrame

convention_df = st.SampleCorpora.ConventionData2012.get_data()
convention_df["party"].iloc[3] = "liberal"
convention_df["party"].iloc[4] = "republican"
convention_df["party"].iloc[5] = "liberal"
convention_df["party"].iloc[6] = "republican"

empath_corpus = st.CorpusFromParsedDocuments(convention_df.iloc[:15],
                                             category_col="party",
                                             feats_from_spacy_doc=st.FeatsFromOnlyEmpath(),
                                             parsed_col="text").build()

html = st.produce_scattertext_explorer(empath_corpus,
    category = 'democrat',
    category_name = 'democrat',
    not_category_name = "Not democrat",
    width_in_pixels=1000,
    use_non_text_features=True,
    use_full_doc=True)

file_name = 'democrat.html'
rel_report_path = os.path.relpath(file_name)
from IPython.display import IFrame    
display(IFrame(filename, width=900, height=650))
```

Juypter returns 404 : Not Found

From what I can see the HTML file was generated , but I cannot get it to display. I use Anaconda.

Comment: Have you verified that rel_report_path matches that of the "democrat.html" file?

Comment: yes, they are the same. Actually, it should make no difference if I just put file_name = 'democrat.html'
rel_report_path = os.path.relpath(file_name)
from IPython.display import IFrame    
display(IFrame(rel_report_path, width=900, height=650))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are never writing the file.

Under `file_name = 'democrat.html`, make sure you include something along the lines of:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as outf: outf.write(html)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it.